# Unable to update webpage with database notifications realtime with SignalR

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am working on a web application developed using Asp.Net MVC which on which I have a page on which data gets updated at realtime whenever data is modified on the database. I have some source on line and tried to implement this feature but it resulted in huge invalid data on the webpage.

I am using SQL dependency and SignalR to achieve this as follows

In `Global.asax`, I have the following

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); 
}
protected void Application_End()
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); 
}
```

and in Models section I have the following classes

```
public class JobInfo 
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastExecutionDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

 public class JobInfoRepository 
 {
    public IEnumerable<JobInfo> GetData()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [JobID],[Name],[LastExecutionDate],[Status]
               FROM [dbo].[JobInfo]", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new JobInfo(){ 
                            JobID = x.GetInt32(0), 
                            Name = x.GetString(1), 
                            LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),  
                            Status  = x.GetString(3) }).ToList();         
            }
        }        
    }
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {            
        JobHub.Show(); 
    }
}
```

I have created a SignalR Hub class as follows which has the `Show()` function used in the above class

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

public class JobHub : Hub
{
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
}
```

And I have the controller in which I am calling `GetData()` method defined in the `JobInfoRepository` class

```
 public class JobInfoController : Controller
{

    // GET: /JobInfo/
    JobInfoRepository objRepo = new JobInfoRepository();

    public IEnumerable<JobInfo> Get()
    {
        return objRepo.GetData();
    }
}
```

I have created an Action named JobInfo in HomeController and returned the following view

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JobStatus</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tblJobInfo" class="clientTable" style="text-align:center;margin-left:10px"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/App/JobInfo.js"></script>
}
```

to retrieve the data and supply it to tblJobInfo id in the above html, a java script function is used

```
$(function () {
    // Proxy created on the fly
    var job = $.connection.jobHub;

    // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
    job.client.displayStatus = function () {
        getData();
    };

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start();
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../JobInfo/',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                var rows = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td></tr>');
                }
                $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As in the demo I found it to be working fine but when I go to `http://localhost:57044/Home/JobInfo/` I get invalid data on the page besides not getting the realtime notifications as in the following image
[image]

reference to the source I found online is http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: I realised that i cannot hit my controller using a breakpoint. not exaclty sure why

Comment: can you post a more concise question that illustrates the problem you're having? this is very tedious to read

Comment: I am just trying to publish data from the database to the webpage and whenever the data is changed in the database the updates should be pushed to the webpage. To be more concise, I am trying to do exactly what the video in http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency  does